# How to build a static tar command

Tags: static-libraries, gnu, tar, static-linking, configure

I downloaded tar 1.28 and am attempting to compile a static binary to use on system recovery media on Fedora Linux (x86_64). It doesn't have to include common libraries, such as libc or pthreads, but I'd like to eliminate dependencies on selinux, acl, attr, pcre and lzma, etc.

The README indicates I can use
     `./configure CC=gcc LDFLAGS=-static`
but this creates a fully static binary (including libc), but is missing support for anything normally found in the shared libraries (SELinux, ACLs, etc). Reading the config.log shows failed attempts to find a static library for acl

So, I installed libselinux-devel-static RPM, and this time got the selinux support in there, but I can't find static libraries for anything else. Search results say that libacl.a is in libacl-devel, but not mine.

A fully static binary is ok, but really just want to get the odd-balls in there so I don't have to put the shared libraries on the media.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this as well, and i would get the following error message:

```
  CCLD     tar
../gnu/libgnu.a(quotearg.o): In function `quote':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/gnu/quotearg.c:968: multiple definition of `quote'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libacl.a(quote.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
names.o: In function `gid_to_gname':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/src/names.c:95: warning: Using 'getgrgid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
names.o: In function `gname_to_gid':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/src/names.c:155: warning: Using 'getgrnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
names.o: In function `uname_to_uid':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/src/names.c:125: warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
names.o: In function `uid_to_uname':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/src/names.c:65: warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
../lib/libtar.a(rtapelib.o): In function `rmt_open__':
/home/anarcat/dist/tar-1.27.1/lib/rtapelib.c:428: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1304: recipe for target 'tar' failed
```

I don't quite get it, but apparently, "[You cannot getpwnam and friends with the whole flexibility that glibc has without shared libraries](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=348)".

So game over? unclear.

Comment: I still haven't gotten an answer and not sure where else to look. For now I'm stuck with using shared libraries which making boot media painful and overly large.

Comment: Yes I've seen those types of messages when trying to statically link in something that itself tries to load a shared library at runtime, which would be version-depenendent. I just want to statically link anything I can without having the entire libc getting statically linked. 

I did finally find a libacl.a file and there are static libraries on the system now for selinux, pthread, attr and rt. But the config script seem to be all or nothing. I can't figure out how to specify flags that'll statically link in selinux, acl, attr, for example, but not libc or pthread.

Comment: This is unfortunate too. I would like for tar to be static and standalone, since sometimes I need to upgrade other components on my system, and tar may fail.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora you can enable Repository [CERT Forensics Tools](https://forensics.cert.org/#repository)
and complete build dependencies with some static libs (non-exhaustive list)

```
zlib-static
libiconv-static
libffi-devel
gettext-devel
pcre-static
ncurses-static
nss-devel
glibc-static
libselinux-static
libsepol-static
libattr-devel
libacl-devel
```

if libacl.a is missing you have to download source first from:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/git/attr.git
git clone https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/git/acl.git
```

and compile with (first libattr, then libacl, then tar):

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-rpath
make CFLAGS='-static'
make install
```

Comment: regarding getpwnam you still have these warnings, but tar will work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bsdtar from libarchive:
https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive

It has some difference from gnu tar.

I prefer apline with musl toolset to make a static builds.

Example code:

```
apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk zlib-dev zlib-static xz-dev zstd-dev zstd-static

./configure LDFLAGS='--static' --enable-bsdtar=static --disable-shared --disable-bsdcpio --disable-bsdcat
make -j$(nproc)

gcc -static -o "bsdtar" \
  tar/bsdtar-bsdtar.o \
  tar/bsdtar-cmdline.o \
  tar/bsdtar-creation_set.o \
  tar/bsdtar-read.o \
  tar/bsdtar-subst.o \
  tar/bsdtar-util.o \
  tar/bsdtar-write.o \
  .libs/libarchive.a \
  .libs/libarchive_fe.a \
  /lib/libz.a \
  /usr/lib/liblzma.a \
  /usr/lib/libzstd.a
```

Full code (and binaries) here: https://github.com/hemnstill/StandaloneTools/blob/master/bsdtar/build_musl.sh